# Removing image overlay on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to remove an image overlay on hover. I have the following code that adds an overlay on hover but I want it to have an opacity when not hovered upon and remove that opacity when hovered.

**jQuery:**

```
revapi1.on('revolution.slide.onloaded', function() {

revapi1.find('li').each(function() {

var slide = jQuery(this);
if(slide.find('.slidelink').length) {

slide.find('.slotholder').addClass('custom-hover');

}

});
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.rev_slider .custom-hover {

-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
-o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;

} 

.rev_slider:hover .custom-hover {

opacity: 0.5;

}
```

I have tried the following. It works but I can't get it to work with the Jquery code above. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4n752zp/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
<figure class="tint">
  <img src="http://cdn.impressivewebs.com/2011-11/greece001.jpg" alt=""   width="400" height="260" />
 </figure>
 </div>
```

Comment: I get a revapi1 is not defined error when I take the code you posted here, please provide with the problematic JSFIDDLE so we can try and help you from there, you posted 2 codes...

Comment: Why use JavaScript when, as you've illustrated in your Fiddle, this is entirely possible using pure CSS? Also the tag names and class names in your JavaScript are different to those in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform a CSS transition on opacity, you'll need to make sure that there is a default opacity property as well. So something like this:

```
.rev_slider .custom-hover {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
} 

.rev_slider:hover .custom-hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```